# Add a title to a to a ggplot pie chart when text = element_blank() is used

Tags: r, ggplot2, pie-chart

I want to make a pie chart **without** any labels, but **with** a title.

However, I do not manage to combine both requirements: or I have a pie chart without a title and without axis (left picture), or I have a pie chart with a title and axis (right picture). See the picture below:
[image: pie problem]

Is it possible to add a title to the left picture, or remove the axis on the right picture?

## DATA

```
data<-structure(list(nuts0 = c("IT", "IT", "IT", "IT", "IT", "IT", 
                         "IT", "IT", "IT", "IT"), variable = structure(1:10, .Label = c("percentage_irri10", 
                                                                                        "percentage_irri20", "percentage_irri30", "percentage_irri40", 
                                                                                        "percentage_irri50", "percentage_irri60", "percentage_irri70", 
                                                                                        "percentage_irri80", "percentage_irri90", "percentage_irri100"
                         ), class = "factor"), value = c(0.100915431560593, 0.0860941586748038, 
                                                         0.0695292066259808, 0.0662598081952921, 0.0745422842197036, 0.0512205754141238, 
                                                         0.0599389712292938, 0.047079337401918, 0.0551438535309503, 0.389276373147341
                         )), .Names = c("nuts0", "variable", "value"), row.names = c(10L, 
                                                                                     25L, 40L, 55L, 70L, 85L, 100L, 115L, 130L, 145L), class = "data.frame")


percentlabelsIT<- round(100*data$value, 0)
pielabelsIT<- paste(percentlabelsIT, "%", sep="")
cols <- c("yellow","greenyellow","#00FF00", "#00C639","#00AA55", "#00718E", "#0055AA", "#001CE3","blue4","midnightblue")
```

## PIE CHART

```
pie <- ggplot(data, aes(x = factor(1), fill = factor(percentlabelsIT))) + geom_bar(width = 1)+
  ggtitle("help")+
  theme(axis.text = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        panel.grid  = element_blank(),
        legend.position="none",
        line = element_blank(),
        text = element_blank()
  )+
  scale_fill_manual(values=cols)
l1<-pie + coord_polar(theta = "y")
l1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (without `text=` but with `axis.title` and `ggtitle`):

```
pie <- ggplot(data, aes(x = factor(1), fill = factor(percentlabelsIT))) + geom_bar(width = 1)+
    ggtitle("help")+
    theme(axis.text = element_blank(),
          axis.title = element_blank(),
          axis.ticks = element_blank(),
          panel.grid  = element_blank(),
          legend.position="none",
          line = element_blank()
    )+
    scale_fill_manual(values=cols)
l1 <-pie + coord_polar(theta = "y") + ggtitle("kdfja")
l1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Didn't know that!